# Kibana has strict security requirements enabled that your current browser does not meet

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jsoup, kibana

I want to write automatic test which tests if there are logs in the kibana UI and I have a problem with sending a http request using java to kibana. From the browser everything is working fine but when I send HTTP request from Jsoup library (the same happens also with curl) the kibana shows me the following:

```
Please upgrade your browser This Elastic installation has strict
security requirements enabled that your current browser does not meet.
```

It looks like the kibana is executing some vulnerable js and if it is executed correctly it stops loading the kibana UI.

```
  <script>
            // Since this is an unsafe inline script, this code will not run
            // in browsers that support content security policy(CSP). This is
            // intentional as we check for the existence of __kbnCspNotEnforced__ in
            // bootstrap.
            window.__kbnCspNotEnforced__ = true;
          </script>
  <script src="/bundles/app/kibana/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Do you have any idea how to work around that from the code? I think that this security feature can be disabled from the kibana.yaml but I don't want to disable it just for the test.

Comment: You'll probably have to set the [UserAgent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) in your code to mimic a compliant browser.

Comment: I had set it but it did not make a difference. The problem is in this content security policy(CSP) which seems the HTTP client does not fulfill.

Comment: JSoup can't run any JavaScript. It is only a parser. So it seems that the kibana website needs JavaScript to render properly. With that your JSoup approach of testing is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up with such automatic test but I want to answer here one possible solution (I did not test it but it should work).

You can use [Headless Chrome browser](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome). It is running a chrome browser without UI which can be used with a chrome driver using selenium library.
More info: https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/introduction-to-chrome-headless/

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to access it on chrome [Version:111.0.5563.64 (Official Build) (64-bit)].
Then I switched to Edge [Version:110.0.1587.63 (Official build) (64-bit)] and it worked fine.